# Column manipulation

Tags: sql, excel

I have a query that generates 8 columns worth of data from a list of unique IDs. These columns are then copied into an excel sheet for holding. I am attempting to find a way to either write a query or find an excel function to get it to generate 2 columns: 1 with the list of unique IDs and the other with the number of times it appears in the initial 8 columns. Any thoughts or comments would be most welcome.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're going to need to post your original query, your current result set, and your desired result set, and the RDBMS you're working with.

Comment: And the version of your RDBMS is also important

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can write a query that returns your two columns.  Unfortunately, it's a little tedious but it should work. This is generic enough to work in any RMDBS.  There are probably more elegant solutions using specific functions of a particular RMDBS.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.UniqueID, SUM(A.IDCounter) AS IDCount FROM
(
SELECT UniqueIDCol1 AS UniqueID, Count(UniqueIDCol1) AS IDCounter
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UniqueIDCol1

UNION ALL

SELECT UniqueIDCol2 AS UniqueID, Count(UniqueIDCol2) AS IDCounter
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UniqueIDCol2

UNION ALL 
.
.
.
SELECT UniqueIDCol8 AS UniqueID, Count(UniqueIDCol8) AS IDCounter
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY UniqueIDCol8

) AS A

GROUP BY A.UniqueID
```

Comment: I'm going to implement this and see how it goes. For more detail all of the data for this is compiled into a temp table that displays the results (#temp6) and will display the following columns:

unique ID, bm1, bm2, bm3, bm4, bm5, bm6, bm7, bm8

We are running SQL Server R2 2008.